# ASP.NET app login is not getting data from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET app and the login was working until a few days ago, now it says user not found but the user is in the database. When I register a new user to test it does create the user and stores it in the database but when I try to login throws the error again.

```html
<div class="form-holder">
    <div class="form-content">
        <div class="form-items">
            <h3>Ingreso al Sistema</h3>
            <p>Software de Gestión Empresarial</p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form", @class = "m-t", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuario">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Clave">
                    <div class="form-button">
                        <!-- llamada al login por  HttpPost  en accountController  -->
                        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="ibtn">Login</button> <!-- <a href="forget18.html">Forget password?</a> -->
                    </div>

                <div class="other-links">
                    @if (ViewBag.Msg != null)
                    {
                        <p style="color:red;">  @ViewBag.Msg  </p>
                    }
                </div>
            }
                <div class="page-links">
                    <a href="~/Account/register">Registrar una cuenta</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the error? And where is your server side code.

Comment: There is no error it just says that the user doesn’t exist

Comment: @Gabriel Show us the server side code, this is useless without it.

Comment: Please share us the code of `Register` and `Login` action methods, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: The thing is I know nothing about asp.net where are the methods? or controllers? I can't find them